# Laravel HasManyThrough is not working with EagerLoading

Tags: laravel, has-many-through, eager-loading

I'm trying to eagerload a `HasManyThrough` relationship with the following models

Surgery

- id

SurgeryUser

- id
- surgery_id
- user_id

User

- id

In the `Surgery` model I have this relation

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        User::class,
        SurgeryUser::class,
        'surgery_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'user_id'
    );
}
```

Then I'm trying a simple test

```
$testWithEagerLoading = Surgery::with('users')->get();
$testWithoutEagerLoading = Surgery::get();

dd(
    $testWithEagerLoading[0]->users,
    $testWithoutEagerLoading[0]->users
);
```

But I got this

[image]

Everything is fine without the eagerLoading (except that I'm making many requests to the DB)

But when using eagerLoading (`->with()`), the relation is empty.

So the eagerLoading seems to break everything. Or did I missed something?

Comment: I think you have to use many to many relationships

Comment: Agreed^  Your data structure above looks like a many to many and not a has many through. Has many through would be like. Users, Doctors, Surgeries and a Doctor has many users through Surgeries.  Where as you just have surgeries_users many to many.

Answer (score -1):

After digging a bit, we realized that an accessor was setup on the Id

```
public function getIdAttribute($value)
{
    return str_pad($value, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

And this was failing all eagerLoading for distant relationships (`hasOne` was somehow working)